# Running into a Value Error when extracting data through the YoBit API

Tags: python, json, api-design

The purpose of this code is to gather data from each currency denominated in BTC on Yobit (a cryptocurrency exchange site).  It does gather the data of a few coins but then runs into an error after about 15 seconds.

Below is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python34\yobit_update.py", line 168, in <module>
main()
File "C:\Python34\yobit_update.py", line 159, in main
datas = pairFinder(table)
File "C:\Python34\yobit_update.py", line 62, in pairFinder
tickerInfo(key)
File "C:\Python34\yobit_update.py", line 85, in tickerInfo
data = response.json()
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 894, in json
return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python34\lib\json\__init__.py", line 318, in loads
return _default_decoder.decode(s)
File "C:\Python34\lib\json\decoder.py", line 343, in decode
obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
File "C:\Python34\lib\json\decoder.py", line 361, in raw_decode
raise ValueError(errmsg("Expecting value", s, err.value)) from None
ValueError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Below is the code:

```
#pip install xlsxwriter
#pip install prettytable
#pip install requests
import xlsxwriter
from prettytable import PrettyTable
from requests import get


pair = ''
last = 0
highestBid = 0
lowestAsk = 0
volume24H = 0
smallPChange = 0
largePChange = 0
smalltolargePChange = 0
smallAsk = 0
largeAsk = 0
smallBuy = 0
largeBuy = 0
myBuy    = 0
myPChange= 0
myAsk    = 0

def fileSaving(datas):
    # Creates the xlsx file
    workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('cryptoInfo.xlsx')
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

    # Creates the headers on file
    headers = {'Pair':'A1', 'Last':'B1', 'Bid':'C1', 'Ask':'D1', 'Volume':'E1', 'My Buy':'F1', 'My Ask':'G1', 'My % Increase':'H1', 'Small Buy':'I1', 'Small Ask':'J1', \
            'Small % Inc':'K1', 'Large Buy':'L1', 'Large Ask':'M1', 'Large % Inc':'N1', 'Small to Large % Inc':'O1'}
    bold = workbook.add_format({'bold':True})   
    for header in headers.keys():
        worksheet.write(headers[header], header, bold)

    # Adds the data to the file
    for row in range(1, len(datas) -1):
        for col in range(0,15):
            worksheet.write(row, col, datas[row][col])

    workbook.close()

def pairFinder(table):
    datas = []
    # Requests data from Yobit's API
    response = get('https://yobit.net/api/3/info')
    data = response.json()

    # Iterates through the data for the pair names
    print('Gathering Data For All: ' + str(len(data['pairs'].keys())) + ' Pairs.'\
          + ' Please Wait A Moment..')
    i = 0
    for key in data['pairs'].keys():
        # Comment print below if you dont want screen spamming with this info
        base = key.split('_')
        if base[1] == 'btc':
            print('Gathering Data Of: ' + key)

            # Gets pair name and sends it through to get searched.
            # Then stores it in variable and creates a table from the data
            tickerInfo(key)
            depthInfo(key)

            # Adds a row to the screen table
            data = [key, last, highestBid, lowestAsk, volume24H, myBuy, myAsk, myPChange, smallBuy, smallAsk, \
               smallPChange, largeBuy, largeAsk, largePChange, smalltolargePChange]
            datas.append(data)

            # Expands the standard form
            for value in range(1, len(data) -1):
                if 'e' in str(data[value]):
                    data[value] = '{0:.8f}'.format(data[value])

            table.add_row(data)
    return datas 


def tickerInfo(pair):
    # Creates local variables
    global volume24H, last, highestBid, lowestAsk

    # Requests data from Yobit's API
    response = get('https://yobit.net/api/3/ticker/' + pair)
    data = response.json()

    # Assigns wanted data to its variables
    volume24H = data[pair]['vol']
    last = data[pair]['last']
    highestBid = data[pair]['buy']
    lowestAsk = data[pair]['sell']

def depthInfo(pair):
    global myBuy, myAsk, myPChange, smallAsk, largeAsk, smallPChange, largePChange, smalltolargePChange, smallBuy, largeBuy, lowestAsk

    # Requests data from Yobit's API
    response = get('https://yobit.net/api/3/depth/' + pair)
    data = response.json()

    # Assigns wanted data to its variables
    try:
        myBuy    = 0.005
        smallBuy = 0.05
        largeBuy = 0.15

        # Sets the Ask price
        y = 0
        for x in range(0, len(data[pair]['asks']) -1):
            y = y + (data[pair]['asks'][x][0] * data[pair]['asks'][x][1])
            if y >= myBuy:
                myAsk = data[pair]['asks'][x][0]
                break
        y = 0
        for x in range(0, len(data[pair]['asks']) -1):
            y = y + (data[pair]['asks'][x][0] * data[pair]['asks'][x][1])
            if y >= smallBuy:
                smallAsk = data[pair]['asks'][x][0]
                break
        y = 0    
        for x in range(0, len(data[pair]['asks']) -1):
            y = y + (data[pair]['asks'][x][0] * data[pair]['asks'][x][1])
            if y >= largeBuy:
                largeAsk = data[pair]['asks'][x][0]
                break

        # Sets the percentage change from inital asking price, (((new - old)/old) * 100)
        myPChange    = ((myAsk - lowestAsk) / lowestAsk) * 100
        smallPChange = ((smallAsk - lowestAsk) / lowestAsk) * 100
        largePChange = ((largeAsk - lowestAsk) / lowestAsk) * 100
        smalltolargePChange = ((largeAsk - smallAsk) / smallAsk) * 100
        print(smalltolargePChange)



        # Change random_pair! to a pair you want to alter/change
        #if pair == 'random_pair!':
                # Add the code you want,
                # smallBuy = (data[pair]['bids'][0][0] * YOUR EDIT VALUE)
                # smallBuy = VALUE

                # largeBuy = (data[pair]['bids'][(len(data[pair]['bids']) - 1)][0] *\
                # YOUR VALUE)
                # largeBuy = VALUE

                # If you want to change multiple values of different pairs just copy the
                # if statement again and change random_pair to the other pair
        #smallBuy = 0.12
        #largeBuy = 0.22
    except:
        pass

def main():
    # Creates table headers
    table = PrettyTable(['Pairs', 'Last', 'Bid', 'Ask', 'Volume', 'My Buy',\
                         'My Ask', 'My % Inc', 'Small Buy',\
                         'Small Ask', 'Small % Inc', 'Large Buy', 'Large Ask',\
                         'Large % Inc', 'Small to Large % Inc'])
    # Starts the data gathering
    datas = pairFinder(table)
    print(table)

    ans = input("Would you like to save this file?")
    if 'yes' == ans.lower() or 'y' == ans.lower():
        fileSaving(datas)  


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

---

This code was working in the past but just recently started having this error

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yobit has a limit of 100 calls per minute after that in bans your requests. Check out the link in the browser to see if you have been temporary banned

https://yobit.net/api/3/ticker/ltc_btc